# Change labels in X axis using plot() in R

Tags: r, plot

I am a beginner in R and am dealing with some data as follows-

> Month <- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
>
> Sales <- 50 60 80 50 40 30 35 55 70 60 50 40

I have to plot these data using the plot() function which I am able to do by doing certain edits to it as follows-

```
plot(Month, Coffee, type='l', ylim=c(0, 100))
abline(h=max(Coffee), col='red')
```

The new requirement is to plot the names of 'Month' which is in X-axis as actual month names viz., January, February, March,....., December.

I tried to do that using-

```
n_month <- format(ISOdate(2017,1:12,1),"%B")
plot(n_month, Coffee, type='l', ylim=c(0, 100))
plot(n_month, Coffee, type='l', ylim=c(0, 100), xlim=(1, 12))
```

I also tried the following-

```
# 'xaxt' to suppress labels on x-axis
plot(Month, Coffee, ylim=c(0,100), xlab="Month", ylab="Coffee", xaxt="n", type='l')

# 'axis' to add in my own labels
axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.name)
```

However, the final graph does not mention all the names but rather certain names like- January, March, May, June, July, September & November.

Any suggestions as to how I can get the names of all 12 months on X-axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I solved it using-

```
axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.name, cex.axis=0.5)
```

The 'cex.axis' argument did the trick of adjusting all month names on the X-axis.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it works for u

```
month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
           "Apr", "May", "Jun",
           "Jul", "Agu","Sep", 
           "Oce", "Nov", "Dec")
sales <- c(50, 60, 80, 50, 40, 30, 35, 55, 70, 60, 50, 40)
dt<-data.frame( Month<-month, Sales=sales   )


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt ,aes( Month,Sales)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill = "Month"), data =dt , alpha = 0.5 )
```

Just make sure u have `ggplot2` in ur system

At the end it would be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In the mean time, I also found a solution which does not have to resort to 'ggplot2' library which is- `axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.name, cex.axis=0.5)`. The 'cex' parameter did the trick!